# PostgreSql + Typecast of Boolean into Character Type

Tags: database, postgresql, sql

Here, I am unable to convert boolean value into character in postgre sql query.

```
SELECT *FROM ltl_class_nmfc_aliases 
WHERE ltl_class_nmfc_aliases.id 
NOT IN(SELECT ltl_class_nmfc_aliases_id FROM commodities_shippeds 
WHERE commodities_shipped_obj_type LIKE 'ClientOffice') 
OR ltl_class_id IS NULL 
AND lower(commodity_description_alias) LIKE E'%%' 
AND lower(ltl_value) LIKE E'%92.5%' 
AND hazardous :: integer LIKE E  '%%' 
AND cast(schedule_b as character varying(255)) LIKE E'%%' 
AND cast(harmonized_tariff as character varying(255)) LIKE E'%%' 
ORDER BY commodity_description_alias,ltl_value LIMIT 25;
```

Here I am unable to typecast at `AND hazardous :: integer LIKE E  '%%'` 
Suggest me how to make typecast ?

Answer (score 8):

How about using a `case` statement?

```
(case when hazardous then 'Bad juju' else 'Ok.' end) as safety
```

You can also use the `cast` statement:

```
postgres=# select cast(1 as boolean);
 bool
------
 t

postgres=# select cast(0 as boolean);
 bool
------
 f

postgres=# select cast('false' as boolean);
 bool
------
 f

postgres=# select cast('False' as boolean);
 bool
------
 f

postgres=# select cast('T' as boolean);
 bool
------
 t

postgres=# select cast('F' as boolean);
 bool
------
 f

postgres=# select cast('Y' as boolean);
 bool
------
 t

postgres=# select cast('N' as boolean);
 bool
------
 f
```

So it could be:

```
 select ... where ... and hazardous = cast(:your_variable as bool)
```

You can also cast to varchar:

```
select cast(hazardous to varchar)...
```

Some database driver implementations (like BDE from Borland) choke on this because they expect an explicit column width for varchar fields.

if you are just filtering for `hazardous=true`, use just "AND hazardous".

Comment: I am trying case at my end but i am not getting any success. I am going to try your code now.

Comment: SELECT * FROM ltl_class_nmfc_aliases LEFT OUTER JOIN ltl_class_nmfcs ON ltl_class_nmfcs.id=ltl_class_nmfc_aliases.ltl_class_nmfc_id LEFT OUTER JOIN ltl_classes ON ltl_classes.id=ltl_class_nmfcs.ltl_class_id WHERE ltl_class_nmfc_aliases.id NOT IN(SELECT ltl_class_nmfc_aliases_id FROM commodities_shippeds WHERE commodities_shipped_obj_type LIKE 'ClientOffice') OR ltl_class_id IS NULL AND lower(commodity_description_alias) LIKE E'%%' AND lower(ltl_value) LIKE E'%92.5%' AND 
case when hazardous then 'True' else 'False' end AND cast(schedule_b as character varying(255)) LIKE E'%%';

Comment: ERROR:  argument of AND must be type boolean, not type text

Comment: in the where clause use "AND (case when hazardous then 'True' else 'False' end)='True'"

Comment: if you are not comparing "hazadous" with something, just filtering for value=true, the correct test is just "AND hazardous"